# Web Scraping value return nothing

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I tried to web scraping data from website. The HTML shows as:

```
   <span class="company-number">913100006073563962</span>
```

I want to get the "9131..." number and export to excel.
And after the running, I got nothing in Excel.

What I wanna achieve is to get a table like: Name Column is the VBA tried to search, and return Number value.. Also the looping process is a little hard..

```
    Name1   234
    Name2   243
    Name3   235
    ...     ...
```

Any help will be highly appreciated!!!

```
    Set HT = IE.Document
    Set CorpNos = HT.getElementsByClassName("company-number")

    i = 1
    For Each CorpNo In CorpNos
      If CorpNo.className = ("company-number") Then
          Sheet1.Cells(i, 3).Value = CorpNo.innerText
          i = i + 1
        End If
```

Comment: <span class="company-number">913100006073563962</span>

Comment: Shouldn't it be `CorpNo.className = ("company-number")`????

Comment: Thanks, that's a typo when I write the question.. still not working when run as this..

Comment: That is too minimum of html elements to choose any unique class name out of it. As you are using IE, it's hard to tell whether you got the desired element within the response. Try using this line `Debug.Print .document.DocumentElement.outerHTML` to check.